# Windows 10 Couldn't boot, replaced HDD, only recognized in bios using SATA0 or SATA1?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, bios, raid, sata

Suffered some sort of failure where my computer wouldn't boot (Windows 10). After trying a few recovery methods unsuccessfully, I figured it was a bad drive, bought a replacement (WD Blue 1TB), but BIOS will only see it if it's connected to either SATA0 or SATA1 (Not the DELL PERC H310 RAID adapter, and not the on-board HDD0-HDD3 ports). So, it works using SATA1 (SATA0 is my DVD drive), but I have another drive with all my files on it that I need to plug in, but it won't show up if I try to use any of the HDD0-HDD3 or Raid Adapter ports...

I've been all through the BIOS tweaking anything and everything (and restoring defaults) and trying different ports and different cables, but nothing seems to be helping.

Any ideas would really be appreciated!

This is a Dell Precision T5600 running Windows 7 Pro, With DELL PERC H310 SATA/SAS Controller, and I'm not quite sure where to find the Motherboard info.

Answer (score 0):

T5600 is using a Intel C600 Chipset. Get drivers for that, and all your ports should word. For the separate adapter you will also need to install its drivers and only then any drive attached to it will be detectable by windows.

Alternately, put the DVD drive on another port and just connect the secondary HDD instead of it.

Also, try to put the HDD0-3 ports in SATA or legacy mode.

Comment: Chipset and Adapter drivers are all installed and up to date. I've got the second HD plugged into the SATA0 port and it works, but now the DVD drive doesn't show up anywhere in the BIOS or Windows...

Comment: Well that happens in windows when there is no correct chipset and/or SATA driver. Are you 100% sure that you have everything installed ? No yellow marks in device manager ? Note that chipsets can have even 3 different SATA controllers and each will need its own drivers. Since you now have this situation, try to hot-plug the ODD in various free ports then refresh disks in disk management to see if it can be detected in any of the free ports.

Comment: Nope, no yellow marks in Device Manager. And at this point I'm using the ports on the motherboard and not the adapter (and I've also tried every configuration I can think of without the adapter installed at all). As far as Windows goes, everything looks as it should, but ultimately, shouldn't the BIOS detect the drives, especially if I'm using the ports on the motherboard?

Comment: Yes, they should be detectable. It's like the rest of the controllers are BIOS-disabled. A BIOS update would be a good idea too. Maybe something is bugged in there.